# golang version of ruby's or-equals ||=

Tags: go

Out of curiosity, what would be the idiomatic way to assign a variable if it's nil in go?

I'm looking for something similar to ruby's `foo ||= bar`

Is there a shorter version of this?

```
if foo == nil{  
  foo = bar
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your version is already the simplest, shortest and idiomatic way to do it.

Comment: This is the list of the current available operators in Go https://golang.org/ref/spec#Operators

Comment: You could, if you really wanted to, implement a `Coalesce()` type function, but it might not be as clean as you'd probably like. https://play.golang.org/p/vzN_4N7Z1N

Comment: Interesting idea! I suppose a function like that could easily break at runtime unless one uses reflection to make sure the passed in types are compatible.